# Maven artifact version number in war file

Tags: gwt, tomcat, servlets, maven, maven-2

I am using Maven 3 for build Dashboard  project

After building my web application i get my war file as Dashboard-0.0.1.war
and deployed this war in my tomcat successfully. well it went fine

but to launch my application i need to hit the URL as

```
http://localhost:8080/Dashboard-0.0.1
```

but  i need use the URL as follows

```
http://localhost:8080/Dashboard
```

without using version number .,

Application is built on GWT and Java servlet

Kindly help out to overcome this problem guys...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either specify in your pom the final name of the war with

```
...
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
...
```

or you can set the context name in Tomcat without changing the filename of the war like this:

```
...
<Context path="/Dashboard" docBase="webapps/Dashboard-0.0.1.war" />  
...
```

Comment: (dance) I used <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>  I got as Dashboard.war     Thanks  Bunting....